# Should a function that normally returns list return a negative int on an exception?

Tags: python, exception

If I have a function that reads a file and returns a list of values, but the file doesn't exist, or have read permissions set for the process, or any other kind of exception, is it better to:

1. let the exception happen organically
2. Try/catch the exception and print the error as a string, and return -1 or some other failure int
3. Try/catch the exception and print nothing, but return -1
4. Try/catch the exception and return the empty list (which is misleading)
5. Something else

In this case we are speaking of Python if it matters.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using pytest or unittest to write tests for your script, effectively breaking it in as many ways as possible. Each time the code breaks, build the appropriate exception handling into your script.  I like printing the errors personally, as it gives the user/developer a clue as to what's breaking. Decide on what the return will be and design the program around that.

Comment: In my opinion, it depends on what the function does and to a certain degree who is going to run your code. If the function is a necessary operation and the program is unable to continue without it, I would throw an error. If it's not necessary and operation can continue without it, catch the error, maybe print a warning, and return -1 to let whatever calls it know that it failed. If your code is being run by python devs, you could let the exception happen. If you expect non-technical users, catch it and print a sensible error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not really Python specific. A general rule about exceptions is that you should only catch them in the context where something can be done to recover from it: e.g. try again every 10 sec up to 3 times, where it makes sense, or ask the user what they want to do: retry, abort?
If the function catching the exception cannot recover sensibly, it is better to let the exception "bubble up". Sometimes, if the context catching the exception can add additional useful information, you can catch the exception, add meaningful information and re-throw a different, more meaningful exception. It really depends on what you are trying to do.
Note that returning an invalid value is a different paradigm of error handling and it makes sense in some situations, but in general, a failure like you describe is better handled through exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

1. let the exception happen organically.

It's up to the caller to decide what to do, so give the caller the information it needs - the exception - and let it decide.  Passing return codes just loses information, and is error-prone to boot.

Answer (score 1):

If you can **guarantee** that the function will **always** be able to *completely* deal correctly with the exception then handle the exception in the function itself and return `None` on failure, since an empty list may be a valid return, and `None` is more Pythonic than an integer return code.

However, it's highly probably that you *can't* make such a guarantee, so you should allow the exception to bubble up to the caller. Or you may compromise by catching the exception, perform some analysis on it (possibly printing a warning message) and then re-raise the exception, or raise a modified version of it with extra error / warning information attached.

This is in accordance with the ancient programmer proverb:

> Never test for an error condition that you don't know how to handle.

:)